# change JSON from [{x:0,y:9},{x:0,y:9}{x:0,y:9}{x:0,y:9}] to [[0,9],[0,9][0,9][0,9]]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wanna change my JSON Data From  `[{x:0,y:9},{x:0,y:9}{x:0,y:9}{x:0,y:9}]` to

`[[0,9],[0,9][0,9][0,9]]`   using javascript or jQuery

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, and not someplace to dump your to-do list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** in javascript

```js
console.log([{
  x: 0,
  y: 9
}, {
  x: 0,
  y: 9
} ,{
  x: 0,
  y: 9
}, {
  x: 0,
  y: 9
}].map(function() {
  return [this.x,this.y];
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that's not valid JSON, valid JSON would be

```
[{"x":0,"y":9},{"x":0,"y":9},{"x":0,"y":9},{"x":0,"y":9}]
```

to change that JSON string to the Array of Arrays, (I assume you don't want that to be JSON as well - if you do, just remove the `JSON.parse`)

```
var result = JSON.parse(oldJSON.replace(/\{\s*("x"|x)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*("y"|y)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*}/gm, '[$1,$2]'));
```